# Mocha: Get current test's name of test generate on loop?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

**This code works:** I used the variable `testTitle` in `beforeEach` function.

```
const list = [
    { title: 'login', uri: '/login', should: 'Login' },
    { title: 'signup', uri: '/signup', should: 'Create'}
];

let testTitle = '';

beforeEach(function() {
    testTitle = this.currentTest.fullTitle();
});

describe('navegation', () => {
    list.forEach(function(item) {
        it(item.title, (done, obj) => {

            // ------------------------------------
            // Not work it
            // console.log(this.test.fullTitle()); 
            // ------------------------------------

            request(server)
                .get(item.uri)
                .expect(constant.STATUS.OK)
                .then(res => {
                    res.text.should.include(item.should);
                    done();
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(testTitle, err);
                    done(err);
                });
        });
    });
});
```

**Question:**

How I can improve my code for used `this.test.fullTitle()` directly on loop and avoid I used the variable `testTitle` and `beforeEach` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within individual tests you have access to `this.test` so you can get `this.test.title` like this:

```
describe('test', function() {
    it('Can read own title', function(done) {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("title: ", this.test.title)        
            done()            
        }, 100)
    })            
})    
// logs: title:  Can read own title
```

You need to be careful with arrow functions (`()=>{}`) however, because you loose access to the `this` context you are depending on.

For example, this **does not work**:

```
describe('test', function() {
    it('Can read own title', (done) => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("title: ", this.test.title)        
            done()            
        }, 100)
    })            
})    

// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark_M particulary about observation `(()=>{})`